# Allow all special characters using imagemagick

Tags: php, codeigniter, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I'm using Imagemagik in PHP codeigniter, I want to allow all special character, smiley etc.. but it's not working. Can anyone help me how to do this. Here is my code.

```
$textonimage = $this->input->post('textonimage');

               if(!empty($background)){
                      $string = $textonimage;
                     
                        $smart_wordwrap_info =  smart_wordwrap($string, 20);
                        $height_1 = substr_count( $smart_wordwrap_info, "\n" );
                        $color_string_length = strlen($colors);
                        if($color_string_length > 7){
                            $colors_result = substr($colors, 3);
                            $colors = '#'.$colors_result;
                        }
                        $height_2 = $height_1+1;
                        $height_3 = $height_2-2;
                        $height_4 = 30*$height_3;
                        $height = 200+$height_4;
                        $image = new Imagick();
                        $draw = new ImagickDraw();
                        $pixel = new ImagickPixel( $colors );
                        $image->newImage(350, $height, $pixel);
                        $image->setImageFormat('png');
                        $image->writeImage(FCPATH.'uploads/post-image/my_output.png');
                        $process_file_path = FCPATH.'uploads/post-image/my_output.png';
                        $target_file_name = mt_rand(10000,99999).'.png';
                        $target_path = FCPATH.('uploads/post-image/'.$target_file_name);
                        $target_path_1 = base_url().'uploads/post-image/'.$target_file_name;
                        exec("convert ".$process_file_path." -gravity center -fill white -font Corsiva -pointsize 30 -interline-spacing 40 -annotate +0+0 '".$smart_wordwrap_info."' ".$target_path);
                        $upload_image[] = $target_path_1;
                        @unlink($process_file_path);
                    }
```

I tried something like this, but it's not working.
exec("convert ".$process_file_path." -gravity center -fill white -font Corsiva -pointsize 30 -interline-spacing 40 -annotate +0+0 '".($smart_wordwrap_info |sed "s/'/\'/g)."' ".$target_path);

Comment: Are these characters defined in the fonts?

Comment: This is coming from this textbox post $textonimage, 150 characters, User can enter the content in this textbox

Comment: @jonThe problem probably isn't with the code. Not all fonts define all characters. In some case there is a "fallback" font for these missing characters, but it other cases there are not.

Comment: Ok, But what is the solution on this?

Comment: Filter you characters in PHP.  Imagemagick has reserved characters that you cannot use.  Also as said above, the font may only allow certain characters. High ascii characters require UTF-8.  Also Imagemagick cannot currently use emojis.

Comment: Yes, I used UTF 8 but still not working